# Calling methods using parent class

Tags: python, class, oop, bioinformatics

I'm very new to object-oriented programing, and I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to manage the relationship between classes that have related data.

I'm trying to represent some genomic information about a series of organisms, which I am eventually going to compare. So I have a `Species` class:

```
class Species(object):
    def __init__(self, species_name, genes={}, contigs={}):
        self.species_name = species_name
        self.genes = genes
        self.contigs = contigs
```

Then I'd like to have a `Gene` class,

```
class Gene(object):
    def __init__(self, locus_tag, annotation, dna_seq, aa_seq):
        self.locus_tag = locus_tag
        self.annotation = annotation
        self.dna_seq = dna_seq
        self.aa_seq = aa_seq
```

The idea is that the `genes` method of `Species` will be a dictionary of `Gene` objects, where the key is the `locus_tag` of the `Gene`. I think I know how to implement this part.

But one of the things I'd like to be able to do is call a function on a `Gene` object that requires knowing what `Species` it's in (it would output a file structure that includes the `species_name` and `locus_tag`, but these are coming from two different classes. The easiest thing I can think of would be to add a `species_name` directly to the `Gene` class, but since each `Gene` will be within a `Species`, this seems redundant.

I'm not even sure where to begin - I did quite a bit of searching, but the other questions I've found are either not relevant, or I don't understand enough to grasp the relevance.

Comment: Does each ```Species``` instance have a unique name?

Comment: As a side note. Never use mutable objects as default arguments. If you need to provide a default mutable argument do the following. `def __init__(self, species_name, genes=None, contigs=None):` and `self.genes = genes if genes is not None else {}`.

Comment: @wwii yes, each species is unique. There may be genes whose names are the same, but their `locus_tag` will be unique.

Comment: Can a ```Gene``` instance (with the same ```locus_tag```) be included in more than one ```Species``` instance?

Comment: @wwii I was about to say no, but I realized that this might not be correct - some of the `locus_tag`s are just numbers, and they are assigned within the `Species`, independently of the other `Species`. So there might be a `locus_tag` in another species that's the same, though this would not imply anything about their relationship. I suppose I could go through and rewrite the `locus_tag`s to have a 2-letter prefix indicating the species, which would make them unique, but this would be less scalable.

Comment: I was asking if any individual ```Gene``` instance/object will be included in more than one species - ```g = {Gene(**kwargs)}; s1 = Species(g, **kwargs); s2 = Species(g, **kwargs)```.  You may be better of with an *external* container, maybe a dictionary, to hold the Gene/Specie relationships.

Answer (score 1):

Create the `Gene` objects, then create the `Species` object by passing the dictionary for `genes` and then update the `Gene` objects by setting the `Species` instance to it, like so:

```
for gene in genes:
    gene.species = species
```

After that each `Gene` instance (`gene`) can refer to its `Species` object by doing `self.species` or, for example, `self.species.species_name` to get the name.

Comment: I'm assuming everywhere you wrote `Series` here you meant `Species`? So if I understand this correctly it's sort of infinitely nested? So I could in principal do `gene.species.genes[locus_tag].species.genes...` etc ad infinitum?

Comment: @kevbonham: yes, I meant `Species` - I have updated the answer. You can indeed keep assigning but it's probably better for your code if you avoid that. However it would work as you're still dealing with objects and you can assign to them.

Answer (score 1):

I would generally not do what you've described. It creates a circular reference, which should be avoided where possible. Objects should generally have a hierarchical relationship. You should be try to find a way to keep a gene and a species reference together where you might need to serialise it.

To be able to serialise a gene you could write a function that takes a species and a gene as arguments. eg.

```
# if using python 2 (I think you might be)
from __future__ import print_function

class Species(object):
    def __init__(self, species_name, genes={}, contigs={}):
        self.species_name = species_name
        self.genes = genes
        self.contigs = contigs

    def serialise(self, fileobj):
        for gene in self.genes.values():
            self.serialise_gene(gene, fileobj)

    def serialise_gene(self, gene, fileobj):
        print(self.name, gene.locus_tag, sep=", ", file=fileobj)
        # prints "name, locus_tag" to the file

s = Species("homo erectus")
with open("some_file.txt", "w") as f:
    s.serialise(f)
```

Comment: Ultimately, these things are going to be written into a database (still need to learn how that works). If I'm understanding you correctly, you're saying that in my `Gene` class, if I want to find the species name I should reach into the database (in your case the `fileobj`) rather than into a different class to know the relationship?